# livewire countdown timer to otp sms login

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

i have a livewire login page that must be authenticated with sms code (otp).

i need a countdown timer (Preferred in mm:ss format) to make delay in sms resend code.
[image]

Comment: And what have you tried so far? I would say rather do this with Alpine

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in Livewire using alphinejs.

```
<div class="grid gap-y-2 text-center" x-data="otpSend(180)" x-init="init()">
  <template  x-if="getTime() <= 0">
   <form wire:submit="resendOtp">
     <button
           type="submit"
           >
     Resend OTP
     </button>
     <input type="hidden" wire:model="otp">
   </form>
  </template>
  <template x-if="getTime() > 0">
  <small>
    Resend OTP in 
    <span x-text="formatTime(getTime())"></span> 
   </small>
  </template>
  </div>
 <script>
   function otpSend(num) {
        const milliseconds = num * 1000 //60 seconds
        const currentDate = Date.now() + milliseconds
        var countDownTime = new Date(currentDate).getTime()
        let interval;

        return {
            countDown: milliseconds,
            countDownTimer: new Date(currentDate).getTime(),
            intervalID: null,
            init(){
                if (!this.intervalID ) {
                    this.intervalID =   setInterval(() => {
                        this.countDown = this.countDownTimer - new Date().getTime();
                    }, 1000);
                }

            },
            getTime(){
                if(this.countDown < 0){
                    this.clearTimer()
                }
                return this.countDown;

            },
            formatTime(num){

                var date = new Date(num);
                return new Date(this.countDown).toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {
                    minute: '2-digit',
                    second:'2-digit'
                });

            },
            clearTimer() {
                    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
            }
            
         }
      }
   </script>
```

Here is a codepen of working sample
https://codepen.io/andychukse/pen/XWQmQXj